# I'm trying to make a gif randomly spawn in an embed, but it spawns the image but not the embed

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Just what the title says, I'm trying to randomly make the bot send gifs and it sends the gif, but not in the embed.

I'm getting this error: `The resource must be a string, Buffer or a valid file stream.`

any help? I tried to code this by myself because there are no tutorials anywhere, and I'm stuck.

```js
if(!message.channel.nsfw){ (message.channel.send) 
            message.channel.send("Please use an NSFW channel for this command."); return;


        } else {    

            if (message.content.startsWith (PREFIX + "stoys")) {
                number = 42;
                imageNumber = Math.floor (Math.random() * (number - 1 + 1)) + 1;
                message.channel.send ( {files: ["./stoys/" + imageNumber + ".gif"]} )

                let files = ["./stoys/" + imageNumber + ".gif"]

                const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .attachFiles({attachment: files}).setImage(files)
                .setColor(0x7732a8)
                .setFooter("BOT IS IN EARLY-ALPHA TESTING (Neon#0999)")
                message.channel.send(embed);


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since files is an array, setImage doesn't take an array, it takes a string. You would have to select an element of the array, or just turn the array into a string by removing the []'s surrounding it.

So, your finished result could be these 2:

```js
let files = ["./stoys/" + imageNumber + ".gif"]

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setImage(files[0])
```

```js
let files = "./stoys/" + imageNumber + ".gif"

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setImage(files)
```

Hope i could help!

Comment: I'm still having trouble, do i keep the `.attachFiles` or do i remove it and add what you put like this

`let files = ["./stoys/" + imageNumber + ".gif"]

                const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setImage(files[0])
                .setColor(0x7732a8)
                .setFooter("BOT IS IN EARLY-ALPHA TESTING (Neon#0999)")
                message.channel.send(embed);`

It says "Invalid body form" and "Not a well formed URL", then i did it with just `files` and it said `Could not interpret "['./stoys/27.gif']" as string.`

Comment: Sorry if i was unclear. Well, your only approach really is to use .attachFiles instead of .setImage because that takes a url, but .attachFiles takes a file path. You can try using what i said but use .attachFiles instead of .setImage. this should fix your problem.

Comment: Now it puts the image and the embed, but the embed is just the footer and description, and the image is outside of the embed on the top of the embed.